# Java / Jersey: How to Create and Use Filters in a Subordinate App

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I have perhaps an unusual question.  I am working on a maven project driven codebase that defines some Jersey JAX-RS resources such as

```
@Path("/some/nifty/path/{thatDoesStuff}")
```

However, this codebase has a dependency, a super-ordinate codebase that defines the Jersey Resource Configuration

```
String[] packages = {"com.example.cool.stuff"};
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages(packages)
    .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

I do not have access to this super-ordinate codebase, only the sub-ordinate codebase, and I need to add Jersey Filters including Request, Response and Logging filters, to this sub-ordinate codebase to handle requests.  How can I accomplish this?

I attempted [the mechanisms found in this tutorial](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) but to no avail as I do not have access to super-ordinate configuration.  As per the tutorial:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyNewFancyRequestFilter.class);
        return classes;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        final Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
        // Register an instance of LoggingFilter.
        singletons.add(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, true));
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //...
        return properties;
    }
}
```

What should I do? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understood the super-ordinate an sub-ordinate stuff. Do you have access to ResourceConfig? Can you extend it? `public class UpperResourceConfig extends LowerResourceConfig {

 public UpperResourceConfig() {
  super();
  
  packages(true, "super.or.sub.ordinate.package.i.am.lost");
  
  register(AuthenticationRequestFilter.class);
 }

}`

Comment: Sorry I cannot format it better. I would add it as an answer but it is so simple that I must have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks, and I think you get the issue.  Basically the resource config is established in a project dependency, representing the super architecture.  Let me try this out, and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Just curious, did it work? I won't add it as an answer, since I read it again and don't really understand your question... Although yes it must have something to do with extending the ResourceConfig. Good luck!

Comment: Its pretty challenging considering current designs, still working on it!  Thanks for checking back!  Stay tuned :)